# How do I show a popup in my Crossrider browser plugin

Tags: crossrider

How can I show a popup programmatically in my Crossrider.com browser plugin?  It works fine to click the button and show it, but I want it to show automatically on certain pages.  I do not see any api method available like appAPI.browserAction.showPopup(), which would be ideal.  I also do not see how to trigger the button click event.  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you to familiarizing yourself with [How to add a browser button to your Crossrider extension](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/howto_browser_action) in general and the button popup feature specifically.

Now, as for triggering the browser button "window open" right from the code - this is not supported through the API as it bad for user experience and in any case not supported in Chrome, so building such support only for Internet Explorer and Firefox seems futile.